# How can I generate polygons like in a Voronoi diagram/Thiessen Polygons and get the nodes for each of the polygons?

Tags: postgis, voronoi-thiessen

I want to be able to generate a set of polygons where I can extract all nodes for every polygon. For example:
[image: Example of the polygons I want to generate]

```
Polygon 1 - (0, 0),(0,2),(2,0)
Polygon 2 - (0, 2),(2,2),(2,0)
Polygon 3 - (0, 2),(5,5),(8,5),(8,0),(2,0)
And so on...
```

I'm not interested in available tools since this is just a part of a project. I want to be able to insert random points to generate this random dataset with polygons and its nodes coordinates.

Where do I start? Is there an algorithm I can implement in a programming language?
BTW: the data is supposed to be used in a PostgreSQL database as geometries.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: If you use the postgis extension in postgresql you can use the function ST_VoronoiPolygons to generate the polygons that you need. If you want to reproduce that maybe you can look at how it was implemented ?